# How to stretch autoshape during animation in Powerpoint 2010?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, animation, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I know how to use a custom animation on an autoshape to move it from one part of the screen to the other but what I'm after is that the it animates to the left while the right side of the rectangle stays fixed on the right. In other words, the shape stretches in a fluent animation. I didn't see an option in the tools but perhaps there's some workaround to accomplish this?